# Unbinding a WebGL buffer, worth it?

Tags: performance, buffer, webgl

In various sources I've seen recommendations for 'unbinding' buffers after use, i.e. setting it to null. I'm curious if there is really a need for this. e.g.

```
var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

// ... buffer related operations ...

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null); // unbinding
```

On the one hand, it's likely better for debugging as you'll probably get better error messages, but is there any significant performance loss from unbinding buffers all the time? It's generally recommended to reduce WebGL calls where possible.

Comment: I've never unbound a buffer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason people often unbind buffers and other objects is to minimize the side effects of functions/methods. It's a general software development principle that functions should only perform their advertised operations, and not have any unexpected side effects. Therefore, it's a common practice that if a function binds objects, it unbinds them before returning.

Let's look at a typical example (with no particular language syntax). First, we define a function that creates a texture without any defined content:

```
function GLuint createEmptyTexture(int texWidth, int texHeight) {
    GLuint texId;
    glGenTextures(1, &texId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, texWidth, texHeight, 0,
                 GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    return texId;
}
```

Then, let's have another function to create a texture. But this one fills the texture with data from a buffer (which I believe is not supported in WebGL yet, but it still helps illustrates the general principle):

```
function GLuint createTextureFromBuffer(int texWidth, int texHeight,
                                        GLuint bufferId) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, bufferId);
    GLuint texId;
    glGenTextures(1, &texId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, texWidth, texHeight, 0,
                 GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    return texId;
}
```

Now, I can call these functions, and everything works as expected:

```
GLuint tex1 = createEmptyTexture(width, height);
GLuint tex2 = createTextureFromBuffer(width, height, bufferId);
```

But see what happens if I call them in the opposite order:

```
GLuint tex1 = createTextureFromBuffer(width, height, bufferId);
GLuint tex2 = createEmptyTexture(width, height);
```

This time, both textures will be filled with the buffer content, because the pixel unpack buffer was still bound after the first function returned, and therefore when the second function was called.

One way of avoiding this is to unbind the pixel unpack buffer at the end of the function that binds it. And to make sure that similar issues can not happen because the texture is still bound, it can unbind that one as well:

```
function GLuint createTextureFromBuffer(int texWidth, int texHeight,
                                        GLuint bufferId) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, bufferId);
    GLuint texId;
    glGenTextures(1, &texId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, texWidth, texHeight, 0,
                 GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    return texId;
}
```

With this implementation, both call sequences of using these two functions will produce the same result.

There are other approaches to address this. For example:

1. Each function documents its preconditions and side effects, and the caller is responsible to make any necessary state changes to meet the preconditions of the next function after calling a function with side effects.
2. Each function is completely responsible for setting up all it's state. In the example above, this would mean that the `createEmptyTexture()` function would have to unbind the pixel unpack buffer, because it relies on none being bound.

Approach 1 does not really scale well, and will be painful to maintain in larger systems. Approach 2 is also unsatisfactory because OpenGL has a lot of state, and having to set up **all** relevant state in every function would be verbose and inefficient.

This is really part of a bigger question: How do you deal with the state based nature of OpenGL in a modular software architecture? Buffer bindings are just one example of state you need to deal with. This is typically not very difficult to handle in small programs that you write by yourself, but is a possible trouble spot in larger systems. It gets worse if components from different sources (e.g. different vendors) are mixed.

I don't think there's one single approach that is ideal in all possible scenarios. The important thing is that you pick one clearly defined strategy, and use it consistently. How to handle this best in various scenarios is somewhat beyond the scope of an answer here.

While unbinding buffers should be fairly cheap, I'm not a fan of unnecessary calls. So I would try to avoid those calls, unless you really feel you need them to enforce a clear and consistent policy for the software you are writing.